# Physical location of SVN checkout project in EC2 using Jenkins CI/CD pipeline

Tags: jenkins, svn, location

I am trying to implement the CI/CD pipeline using Jenkins , docker and ansible in my AWS EC2 machine. I am panning to create a declarative pipeline for building all my CI/CD pipeline stages. And I am using one SVN private repository in my on-premise server.

When I am using svn chekcout command in checkout stage , to where the SVN project is chekouting?  Where is the physical location of SVN project in my EC2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pipeline will checkout your repo in the job’s workspace directory. Check the below location on the node where you are executing your pipeline.

JENKINS_HOME/workspace/{pipeline}